# Samsung SyncMaster 2033 Monitor Not working properly

Tags: resolution, monitor, samsung

I have a samsung sync master 2033 Monitor with a resolution of 1600x900 px. A few days earlier Ubuntu started behaving absurdly, It didn't recognise the monitor and now I'm stuck with 1024x768 px resolution.

The specs can be found here http://j.mp/16CNsGb

This is the monitor setting screenshot, Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work well in windows7 either

Comment: After a few reboots it worked properly but after another reboot it started the absurdity, is it the problem of boot or the drivers?

Answer (score 0):

For unknown reasons my older Samsung Sync Master monitor (not the same model as yours) does not work properly with the DVI connection to my Ubuntu server after every re-boot.

If I either cycle the power or depress the change input (between digital and analog) button, thereafter it works properly. (Including automatically detecting active digital video input and switching back to it.)